Unable to locate a class or view for component [theme-tabler::menu-dropdown]
<x-theme-tabler::menu-dropdown title="Authentication" icon="la la-group">
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Users" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('user')" />
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Roles" icon="la la-group" :link="backpack_url('role')" />
    <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Permissions" icon="la la-key" :link="backpack_url('permission')" />
</x-theme-tabler::menu-dropdown>

I have problems with laravel backpack dropdown menu. When I am adding menu items inside dropdown I get this error: Unable to locate a class or view for component [theme-tabler::menu-dropdown].
Menu items is working outside of dropdown. Could you please help to understand where is the problem?
composer dump-autoload

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are using:
<x-theme-tabler::menu-dropdown title="Authentication" icon="la la-group">
     <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Users" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('user')" />
     <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Roles" icon="la la-group" :link="backpack_url('role')" />
     <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Permissions" icon="la la-key" :link="backpack_url('permission')" />
</x-theme-tabler::menu-dropdown>

But you should use(notice the difference: ~x-theme-tabler~):
<x-backpack::menu-dropdown title="Authentication" icon="la la-user" nested="true">
     <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Users" icon="la la-user" :link="backpack_url('user')" />
     <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Roles" icon="la la-group" :link="backpack_url('role')" />
     <x-backpack::menu-dropdown-item title="Permissions" icon="la la-key" :link="backpack_url('permission')" />
</x-backpack::menu-dropdown>

resources/views/vendor/backpack/ui/inc/menu_items.blade.php
For more info, check this section of docs.

I was trying this too before, but when I added this code. It gives another error: Undefined variable $nested.

The package is working OK;
Please recheck at your end and share more details.

I was trying this too before, but when I added this code. It gives another error: Undefined variable $nested.

I define :nested="false", but it still have this error.
2.php artisan cache:clear,  php artisan view:clear this is also not helped.


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
